# Linux mknod-command

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

What does this command do?

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/fuse c 10 229
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It creates a character device node with major number 10, minor number 229 and global read and write permissions. From the name, it looks like the [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net) device.

Comment: And in fact, looking at `/proc/devices` (character major 10 = misc) and `/proc/misc` (misc minor 229 = fuse) would confirm this.

Answer (score 4):

Read

[Linux / Unix Command: mknod](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_mknod.htm)

mknod:  make block or character special files

-m, --mode=MODE:  set permission mode

Comment: I should have been more accurate. I use curlftpfs to embed a ftp-server to the local filesystem of my linux workstation. 
It works without the mknod command. The command is stated in the tutorial I've used for installing curlftpfs. This is somehow confusing.